# How can I connect a keyboard to HTC Evo 3D?

Tags: htc-evo-3d, external-keyboard

I have HTC Evo 3D, unrooted, with stock Android 4.0.3. I need to connect a keyboard to it so that I can type quickly to the phone.

If required, I can root the phone. If required, I can also install a custom ROM to it, although I'd prefer avoiding this. If required, I can pay for an android application.

I'd like to connect a wired keyboard to it, but I can also use wireless, if necessary.

I tried this already with my logitech wired keyboard + USB female -> micro USB adapter and nothing really happened. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible. The OS needs to be able to process the I/O signals the keyboard sends, and I don't think it supports that. What you can do is experiment with different keyboard apps, I use swiftkey and I had GO Keyboard before that. Practice often and develop a feeling for how well your keyboard can predict and what it will predict, you'll be typing quite fast in a matter of weeks...